# Adding and removing elements to a double ended queue

Tags: java, queue

I have a to create a double ended queue which can add,remove and peek elements from both sides (i.e, front and rear)

I got the methods for the adding,removing and peeking the elements at the 'head' but i am unable to figure out the methods to do the same thing to the 'tail' of the queue

Here is my code so far:-

```
public class dequeue
{
    private Node rear;
    private Node front;
    private int counter;

    class Node 
    {
        private String item;
        private Node link;
    }

    public Node()
    {
        rear = front = null;
        counter = 0;
    }

    public void hAdd(String o)
    {
        Node temp = new Node();
        temp.item =o;
        temp.link =null;

        if (rear==null)
            front = rear = temp;

        else
        {
            rear.link = temp;
            rear = temp;
        }
        counter++;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        if(counter==0)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public Object hPeek()
    {
        return rear.item;
    }

    public Object hRemove()
    {
        if (isEmpty())
            return null;

        else    
        {
            Object temp=front.item;
            front = front.link;

            if (front == null)
                rear = null;
            counter--;
            return temp;
        }
    }

    public int size()
    {
        return counter;
    }

    public void tAdd(String o)
    {
        Node temp = new Node();
        temp.item =o;
        temp.link =null;

        if (front==null)
            front=rear=temp;

        else
        {
            front.link=temp;
            front=temp;
        }
        counter++;
    }

    public Object tPeek()
    {
        return front.item;
    }

    public Object tRemove()
    {
        if (isEmpty())
            return null;

        else
        {
            Object temp=rear.item;
            rear=rear.link;
            if (rear==null)
            front=null;
            counter--;
            return temp;
        }
    }


    public String toString()
    {
        StringBuilder result=new StringBuilder();
        Node curr=front;
        while(curr!=null)
        {
            result.append(curr.item+" \n");
            curr = curr.link;
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

Comment: You need to fix your code first: the `Node` constructor is not defined in the class `Node` so this can't work properly. Also you need to maintain a head and a tail for each node, so your definition of `Node` isn't defined well as a node only has one "link". Tip:  if you compare "head" operations to "tail" operations, they should be pretty symmetric. Your code could reflect that.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Dequeue {
    int arr[];
    int front;
    int rear;
    int size;


    public Dequeue(int size){
        this.front = -1;
        this.rear=0;
        this.size = size;
        arr = new int[size];
    }
     public Dequeue(){
        this.front = -1;
        this.rear=0;
        this.size = 10;
        arr= new int[size];
    }

    boolean isQueueEmpty(){
        return (front == -1);
    }
    boolean isQueueFull(){
        return front == ((rear+1)%size);
    }
    int getFront(){
        if(isQueueEmpty()){
            return -1;
        }
    return arr[front];
    }
    int getRear(){
        if(isQueueEmpty() || rear < 0){
            return -1;
        }
    return arr[rear];
    }

    void insertFront(int data){
        if(isQueueFull()){
            System.out.println(-1);
            return; 
        }
        if(front == -1){
            front = 0;
            rear=0;
        }
        else if(front == 0){
            front = size - 1 ; 

        }else{
            front = front-1; 
        }
        arr[front] = data; 

    }
    void insertRear(int data){
        if(isQueueFull()){
            System.out.println(-1);
            return; 
        }
        if(front == -1){
            front =0;
            rear=0;
        }
       else{
           rear =((rear+1)%size);
       }
        arr[rear] = data ; 

    }

    void deleteFront(){
        if(isQueueEmpty()){
            System.out.println("-1");
            return; 
        }
         if(front == rear){ 
            front = -1; 
            rear = -1; 
        }else{
        front = ((front+1)%size);
         }

    }
     void deleteRear(){
        if(isQueueEmpty()){
            System.out.println("-1");
            return; 
        }
        if(front == rear){
            front =-1;
            rear=-1;
        }
        else if(rear == 0) 
        rear = size-1; 
        else
        rear = rear-1; 

    }  }
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation along with your answer.